# Example in Scala of hashmap forall() method?

Tags: scala

Can someone please give an example of how to use the HashMap forall() method? I find the Scala docs to be impenetrable.

What I want is something like this:

```
val myMap = HashMap[Int, Int](1 -> 10, 2 -> 20) 
val areAllValuesTenTimesTheKey = myMap.forall((k, v) => k * 10 == v)
```

but this gives:

```
error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need instead

```
val myMap = HashMap[Int, Int](1 -> 10, 2 -> 20) 
val areAllValuesTenTimesTheKey = myMap.forall { case (k, v) => k * 10 == v }
```

The problem is that forall wants a function that takes a single `Tuple2`, rather than two arguments. (We're thinking of a `Map[A,B]` as an `Iterable[(A,B)]` when we use `forall`.) Using a case statement is a nice workaround; it's really using pattern matching here to break apart the `Tuple2` and give the parts names.

If you don't want to use pattern matching, you could have also written

```
val areAllValuesTenTimesTheKey = myMap.forall(p => p._1 * 10 == p._2 }
```

but I think that's less helpful.

Comment: I'm accepting this one as it was the first reply to include the non-pattern matching answer (which I think is the simplest answer for a scala newbie to understand). Thanks @Scott.

Answer (score 8):

`forall` is passed a single `(Int, Int)` Tuple (as opposed to multiple parameters). Consider this (which explicitly shows a single tuple value is decomposed):

```
val areAllValuesTenTimesTheKey = myMap.forall(t => t match { case (k, v) => k * 10 == v })
```

Or, the short-hand (which actually passes a PartialFunction):

```
val areAllValuesTenTimesTheKey = myMap.forall {case (k, v) => k * 10 == v}
```

(These both decompose the tuple take in.)

Additionally, the function can be "tupled"ed:

```
val myMap = Map((1,10), (2,20))
val fn = (k: Int, v: Int) => k * 10 == v
val tupled_fn = fn.tupled
val areAllValuesTenTimesTheKey = myMap.forall(tupled_fn)

myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map((1,10), (2,20))
fn: (Int, Int) => Boolean =          // takes in two parameters
tupled_fn: ((Int, Int)) => Boolean = // note that it now takes in a single Tuple
areAllValuesTenTimesTheKey: Boolean = true
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code, is that you give `forall` method a function, that accepts 2 arguments and returns `Boolean`, or in other words `(Int, Int) => Boolean`. If you will look in the documentation, then you will find this signature:

```
def forall (p: ((A, B)) => Boolean): Boolean
```

in this case `forall` method expects `Tuple2[A, B] => Boolean`, so it also can be written like this:

```
def forall (p: Tuple2[A, B] => Boolean): Boolean
```

In order to fix your example you can either call `forall` and give it function, that accepts 1 tuple argument:

```
myMap.forall(keyVal => keyVal._1 * 10 == keyVal._2)
```

or you make patterns match and extract key and value:

```
myMap.forall {case (k, v) => k * 10 == v}
```

In this case you are giving `PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Boolean]` to the `forall` method